# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.GroupBoxArray' is obsolete

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, vb6, vb6-migration

I was converting VB6 to VB.NET and now I came across this warning.

I made research before and the result is comment relate statement then add new code if necessary. it is so far so good until I faced an others problem that after comment.

I commented obsolete warning but it made `AxMSFlexGrid Array.AxMSFlexGrid Array.GetIndex not found`(I got 7 warning about this). The problem made the design view can not show fully which just like the following picture. http://chanmingman.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/couldfindtype.jpg

But no longer, I don't know what happen or what have I done, it gone.

I want to know why. Anyone came across this situation like that?

Answer (score 0):

It is obsolete in .Net 4. That means it works now, but it might be removed in future versions of .Net. You should probably just leave it, since you are having trouble understanding the code.